# The values of $n$ which satisfy an inequality about prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, inequalities

For which values of $n$ does the following inequality hold for?

> $$2(n-2) < Ap_n\prod_{i=3}^n \left(\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}\right)$$

$p$ are prime numbers and the notation $p_i$ indicates the $i$-th prime number as per convention.

$A$ is defined by the following relationship $p_n = 6A + r$ and $0\leq r<6$

---

**Context**

The inequality comes from this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718774/a-necklace-problem-related-to-the-modulo-function)

Comment: Since A is greater than n/6, you should show by elementary means ( using  a theorem of Mertens if needed ) that A times the product is greater than 1 for n greater than 5.  This and a small amount of computation should establish the inequality for n greater than 3.  Gerhard "Mertens Often Makes Things Simpler" Paseman, 2016.03.29.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a proof that the inequality holds for $n\geq 9$. I let you verify the remaining cases $n\leq 8$.

Let $x:=p_n$ so that $x\geq 23$ by $n\geq 9$. Then the inequality can be rewritten as
$$ 2\bigl(\pi(x)-2\bigr)<\left\lfloor\frac{x}{6}\right\rfloor x \prod_{3\leq p\leq x}\frac{p-1}{p}.$$
By increasing the LHS and decreasing the RHS, we get the following stronger inequality:
$$ 2\pi(x)<\frac{(x-5)x}{6}\prod_{3\leq p\leq x}\frac{p-1}{p}.$$
We shall further increase the LHS and decrease the RHS by using the bounds in the famous paper of Rosser-Schoenfeld (1961): Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers. Using (3.6) and (3.27) in this paper, we see that it suffices to show
$$ \frac{8 x}{3\log x}<\frac{(x-5)x}{6\log x}\left(1-\frac{1}{\log^2 x}\right),$$
that is,
$$ 16 < (x-5) \left(1-\frac{1}{\log^2 x}\right).$$
However, this last inequality is clear by $x\geq 23$. Done.

**Added.** The OP mentioned in a comment the following [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720346/which-values-of-n-is-this-inequality-related-to-prime-numbers-true-for). This can be solved in much the same way, using that
$$ \left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)^3<\frac{p-2}{p}. $$
So, unless $x$ is very small, the sharper inequality in the above related problem is also true.

Comment: GH from MO, it is nice solution!

Comment: Thank you very much; a related problem (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720346/which-values-of-n-is-this-inequality-related-to-prime-numbers-true-for?noredirect=1#comment3512112_1720346)

Comment: @BradGraham: See my Added section.

Comment: @BradGraham: In your 2 stackexchange posts, please mention the above response of mine (to avoid duplicate efforts).

Comment: @GHfromMO I've done that! Thank you so much for your answer, has really helped!

Comment: Also quoted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720837/is-this-proof-of-the-twin-prime-conjecture